# Understanding why a question is well received and another not

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, when I saw this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8020/radio-or-podcasts-for-french-language-learners) ("Radio or podcasts for French language learners?"), I was quite sure it will be closed as opinion-based or too broad or something like that.

And in fact (strangely to me), it has been very well received in itself and had 6 answers.

But more recently, this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27239/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-french-for-beginners), have been put on hold for a bit non clear reason, in my opinion.

About the first question: what is the limit to "opinion-based" questions and answers?

Concerning the second one: is it mainly (and simply) because its title should have been rephrased in something like "Books or websites for French language learners"?

PS: for your information, I have edited the title of the second one and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que la seule différence est que la première question a eu de nombreuses réponses et été vu un nombre important de fois (>4000) ce qui fait que personne n'a voulu la fermer, mais il me semble que c'est une règle générale de SE que ce genre de questions, qui demandent des références, sont interdites (règle d'après laquelle la première question aurait du être fermée).

Personnellement, je n'ai rien contre l'idée de déroger à la règle générale de SE et permettre de poser des questions pour des références, cependant c'est une décision qu'il faut prendre collectivement, sinon la politique de fermeture ne sera pas cohérente. Il y a évidemment un risque que les nouveaux arrivants respectent les règles générales et votent pour la fermeture de ces questions.

Comment: Je suis d'accord, et dans la pratique ça peut être utile pour beaucoup de gens qui cherchent à apprendre et se renseigner. D'autant qu'une fois ces quelques sujets traités (peu de questions, finallement) les autres seront au pire 'duplicate'.

Comment: @lemon & Disctic, j'irais dans ce sens également, la règle générale sur SE de bloquer les questions à liste vient du fait que les réponses deviennent vite obsolètes. Cependant dans le cas d'une langue comme le Français, il y a peu de chance qu'un livre cité devienne obsolète hormis à très long terme.